# How to call a php function with html <form> action attribute?

Tags: php, html, action

Hi guys I'm having difficulties with trying to call a function when I use the html `<form>` action attribute.

```
$cm = new customer_module();
$rm = new room_module();

$c_array = $cm->getByStatus('CHECKED-IN');

foreach($c_array as $row)
{
    $temp = $row['room_no'];
    $r_array = $rm->getByRoomNumber($temp);
    $rray = $r_array[0];
    echo( 
    $cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']).
    "<tr>".
    "<td>".$row['room_no'].     "</td>".
    "<td>".$rray['type'].       "</td>".
    "<td>".$row['last_name'].   "</td>".
    "<td>".$row['first_name'].  "</td>".
    "<td>".$row['phone_no'].    "</td>".
    "<form action="$cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']);">".
    "<td>"."<Button>Check Out</button>"."</td>".
    "</form>".
    //"<td>"."<input type='button' name='checkingOut' value='Check Out' />"."</td>".
    "</tr>");
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to run the code `$cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name'])` for the action attribute.

The code runs fine for the first line after my echo, but when I pasted it for action it seems there is a syntax problem with `$cm`.

Please advise me what the problem is and thanks a lot!

Comment: If we knew what "$cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name'])" did then we could help you better.

Comment: Basically my page displays a table of all customers who are currently checked in.  I would like to create a "check out" button for each customer displayed in the table.  I want to be able to click on "check out" beside that customer to modify their status to checked out.  Basically my checkOutCustomer function would search for the customers last name and first name then change their status from "Checked In" to "".

Answer (score 3):

If you want that `checkOutCustomer` method should execute when the form is submitted, then its not the correct way to implement. You need to specify a url in the action attribute. The form will be submitted to this url where you can access the form fields as the elements of $_POST or $_GET super globals (depending upon the method) and then process them.

But in case this method `checkOutCustomer` returns a url that you want to set as the action attribute of the form, then

instead of

```
"<form action="$cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']);">".
```

try

```
"<form action=" . $cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']) . ">".
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why @sdleihssirhc's answer was voted down when it was right, and the wrong answers got upvotes. PHP is evaluated server side - HTML is processed by the browser. This means your code currently checks out every user as they are listed. Not what you want? Didn't think so.

The `action` attribute is **NOT** for executing **server side** functions on submits. You want to set it to a PHP file and have that PHP file do your processing. Try going over the basics of HTML forms again too, because you don't seem to understand.

Also try to create a `Customer` class and just add a `$customer->checkout()` method, and just do a search for active customer records (i.e. not checked out) and display info from those. And then do something like `$customer = new Customer($roomNo, $info ...)` and then `$customer->checkIn()`

It just makes more sense to anyone maintaining the system. Anyway, from what I can see, you're trying to create a hotel management system. PHP isn't the best suited language for the job at hand and **don't** give any of that "only language i know" crap - learn something suited to the task, because lack of knowledge is no excuse for picking a bad language for the job at hand.

--

I *won't* give **any** working code apart from small things or pointers - you have to *learn*, rather than have others do and just copy / paste.

Comment: What makes you think that the OP is trying to open PHP source code in a browser? To me it's actually pretty obvious in his question that is not the case. While the information in sdleihssirhc's answer is correct, it's not the "right" answer for the question. If you go back and look at the code, the problem is the syntax that is used to insert the action attribute into the echo statement.

Comment: Wow :S You do understand that the `action` attribute specifies a page to send data to, right? If you set `action` to `myFunc()` then `myFunc()` is executed on page load, the action is set to the return value of `myFunc()` and you've screwed up everything. And you guys vote correct answers down...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is evaluated by the server.

HTML is interpreted by the client.

Never the twain shall meet.

There are two options:

1. Move your function to a separate page. Set the form's action to that page. This would require some redirecting, to send the user back to the page with all of the table rows.
2. Move your function to a separate page. Use JavaScript to cancel the form's submission, and then use AJAX to send the data to that separate page. This kind of sucks, because you'll have to handle cross-browser events and AJAX, so I'd suggest a library, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong.

```
"<form action="$cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']);">".
```

This should work.

```
"<form action=" . $cm->checkOutCustomer($row['last_name'],$row['first_name']) . ">" .
```

Looks like a copy and paste error is all.